# Npgsql: what to use instead of NpgsqlConnection.MapCompositeGlobally?

Tags: npgsql

I have a statement in my old Npgsql based c# project

NpgsqlConnection.MapCompositeGlobally<TransferToPgSql.SqlVariant>(@"sql_variant");

VS2022 writes it is an error.
How to replace it?